# How to construct dynamic function invocation with variable arguments in Python

Tags: python, argument-passing, variadic-functions

I'm attempting to wrap a call to an operation with a variable argument list into a generalized function with fixed arguments like this:

```
def vectorizeIt(args, op)
```

`op` is a function with a variable number of arguments and `args` is a list with the arguments I'd like to pass to it.  For example if `len(args) == 3` then I'd like to call `op` like this: `op(args[0],args[1],args[2])`.  As far as I can tell, `op` needs to have the arguments explicitly passed like that; I can't change the argument list to just be a single list or dictionary.  Any suggestions about how to do this are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ["splat" operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) `*` to apply an arbitrary number of arguments to `op`:

```
def vectorizeIt(args, op):
    op(*args)
```

---

Reference:

- [Salty Crane: How to use *args and **kwargs](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) (also linked aboved)
- [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (official docs)

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I can skip `vectorizeIt` all together!